# undefined method for form fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a advanced search form. I am working in views/searches. Now I have attributes created for user profiles that I have been using such as zip code, age, gender, career, religion, education, etc. I want to use these fields for my advanced search.

When I include the f.label and text fields I get a undefined method. I'm hoping I don't have to recreate each attribute for the search form, as that would not make much sense considering I have already done all these attributes for the user profile. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

`/searches/new.html` (for search):

```
<%= form_for @search do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :keywords %><br/>
        <%= f.text_field :keywords%>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :zip_code %><br/>
        <%= f.text_field :zip_code %>
    </div>

    <div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Search" %></div>
    <% end %>
```

/users/new.html (for the user profile):

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div class="error_messages">
      <h2>Form is invalid</h2>
      <ul>
        <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :email %><br/>
        <%= f.text_field :email %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :password %><br/>
        <%= f.password_field :password %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :username %><br/>
        <%= f.text_field :username %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :zip_code %><br/>
        <%= f.text_field :zip_code %>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">I'm a
            <%= f.select :gender, ['man', 'woman']%>
            interested in 
            <%= f.select :gender, ['women', 'men', 'both']%>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
            Age <%= select(@object, :age, (18..75).to_a) %> to  <%= select(@object, :age, (18..75).to_a) %>
            </div>
    <div class="actions"><%= f.submit %></div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: It's for both of them.

Answer (score 1):

Your `@search` object is a `Search` object (or whatever it actually is), not a `User`.

Rails doesn't know your `Search` object doesn't actually have those fields, so when it tries to retrieve the fields that don't exist, it'll blow up.

There are any number of ways around this, including giving your `Search` a `User` property.

You could also create a new `User` and pass it to a user form partial as `f`, that's probably the approach I would take, although I don't know precisely what it would look like without trying it.

Comment: The search object does not have those fields. The user object is the one that has all those fields stored as I had to create them for users profiles. My thinking is that despite these being two different objects, I should still be able to pull fields from the User object to use in the Search object. Why create duplicate fields? At the end of the day the Search engine is strictly for searching the website to find a specific type of profile. So if I have to create duplicate fields for search object...it would cancel out the search engine pulling information it needs from user profiles.

Comment: @pwz2000 I know it doesn't, that's what I said. When you're calling stuff on `f` it thinks you're dealing with the *form's* object, because you are. I told you two options, there are likely others. No clue how you missed that.